# Can I terminate an epoch (and go to the next round of weight initialization) based on validated loss with keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am training a convolutional neural network in Keras, using Tensorflow in the backend. To do so, I want to do 100 rounds with max 12 epochs per round.

What I walked upon until now is that after six to ten epochs, the validated loss starts to increase while the loss still decreases. Since I expect this to be due to overfitting, I would love to terminate this particular round and proceed to the next round after the validated loss starts to increase (for 2 rounds).

Does Keras come with an option to do this? And what are the search words to look for in their documentation?

Comment: What do you mean by "next round of weight initialization"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop training early but Keras will not let you terminate the training mid-epoch, only after the epoch has finished.

EXAMPLE:

```
from keras import callbacks

early_stopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto')

model.fit(X_train,
          y_train,
          epochs=10,
          batch_size=64,
          validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
          callbacks=early_stopping)
```

Another method you could try is to reduce the learning rate.

```
early_stopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto')
reduce_lr = callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=8, min_lr=0.0001, verbose=1)


model.fit(X_train,
          y_train,
          epochs=10,
          batch_size=64,
          validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
          callbacks=[early_stopping, reduce_lr])
```

Make sure the `patience` is set at different values in order for the model to, for example, adjust for the learning rate first after 5 epochs without improvement in `val_loss` and then stop the training altogether after 8 epochs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I implemented both options indeed with different patience. I found that a lot of people use a factor of 0.2 to reduce their learning rate (LR). How can I interpret this factor? Is the current LR multiplied by this factor?

Comment: per official Keras documentation - factor: factor by which the learning rate will be reduced. new_lr = lr * factor. So yes, you are correct.

Comment: Also, please, accept the answer if it was of any help to you. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean 'upvoting' by accepting? I did upvote it, but I don't have sufficient reputational points for it to be displayed on the screen. Thanks anyway!

Comment: That was a different answer you've upvoted, not mine. Nevermind though, hope you were able to solve whatever issues you've had.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Early Stopping as described here:

[EarlyStopping](https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping)

Comment: set patience = 2 if you want it to keep going for two rounds after it stops improving.